# Why this linear program has no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Consider bellow  LP constraints:

$$-1\ge x_1-x_4\\
-4\ge x_2-x_1\\
-9= x_2-x_3\\
5\geq x_3-x_1\\
-3\geq x_4-x_3
$$

How is it possible to show that the above constraints have no solution?

Comment: What have you tried?  What are the constraints on each individual $x_i$, where $1 \leq i \leq 4$?

Comment: False assertions are sometimes more difficult to prove than true assertions.  I guess that you would have to mesmerize the audience.  Consider $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0,-4,5,2).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $-9=x_2-x_3$, you can replace $x_2$ by $x_3-9$ in others inequations. Setting $(x,y,z)=(x_1,x_3,x_4)$, the inequations can be written as
$$
\begin{cases}
x-z\leq -1\\
y-x\leq 5\\
z-y\leq -3
\end{cases}
$$
You can thus represent it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to see the set of solutions (one solution is given in comments). It's the set
$$\{(x,y,z):x\in \mathbb{R}, y\in[x+4,x+5],z\in [x+1,y-3]\}$$